Extract email information for approval process with apex
Through a flow I am sending an email to a specific user "A" and that user has to respond to the email and that email has to reach Salesforce, so that it knows what I answered, since it depends on whether it is approved or rejected Quote, apart from the fact that it has to send data to update certain fields in the Quote, for that I am going to use Email Services.
When making the apex I have some complications with the code which I don't know if I am correct when extracting the data from both the subject and the body of the email
Example of email upon receiving the email sent by the user will come in the following form:
Subject: Approve or Reject Quote XXXYXXX Test Committee4 - PURCHASE - 24050614038
I extract only the end of the Subject, which are the numbers "24050614038"
Body: Approve
LTV: 30%   Percentage type variable in the quote
Amount: $32,000  Currency type variable in the quote
In the Body I want to obtain the word Approve and after the Quote is approved or if it has Rejected the Quote is rejected, also for it to be reflected in the status of the approval history (I'll give you an image of what I mean)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Also if the body of the email contains more data, for example if it finds the word LTV, look for the value to put it in the corresponding field. If it does not include anything, it is null and the same for the Amount.
I put the code that I have done so far, you can help me know how I can do what I am missing, as far as I am going I don't know how to extract the information from the body, but still if you see something else you could tell me and help me improve
global class MyInboundHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
      Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
       
    String emailBody;       
        if (email.plainTextBody != null){
            emailBody = email.plainTextBody;
        } else {
            emailBody = email.htmlBody;
        }
    system.debug(emailBody);        
    //Extract only the end numbers
    String subject = email.subject;
    String numcredito = subject.substringAfter('PURCHASE - ');
    system.debug(numcredito); 
    
    Set<Id> qtIds = (new Map<Id, Quote>([SELECT id From Quote where id_sf__c= :numcredito LIMIT 1])).keySet();
    Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :qtIds])).keySet();
    Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();
    
    List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>();
    
    for(Id pInstanceWorkitemsId:pInstanceWorkitems)
    {
        system.debug(pInstanceWorkitemsId);
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req2.setComments('mRequest.');
        if(emailBody.contains('APPROVED') || emailBody.contains('APPROVE') || emailBody.contains('YES'))
        {
            req2.setAction('Approve'); 
        }
        else if(emailBody.contains('REJECT') || emailBody.contains('REJECTED') || emailBody.contains('NO'))
        {
            req2.setAction('Reject'); 
        }
        req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
        req2.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);
        requests.add(req2);
    }
    Approval.ProcessResult[] result2 =  Approval.process(requests);
     
      return result;
}

}
Also testing with a test class, I don't get any errors, but it doesn't enter the for, I also leave the test code
@isTest

private class YVTestReplayEmail {
static testMethod void testReplayEmail() {
Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
    email.subject = 'Approve or Reject Quote XXXYXXX Prueba Approval Comite2 - PURCHASE - 24050414036';
    email.plainTextBody = 'APPROVE';

    MyInboundHandler creatC = new MyInboundHandler();
    creatC.handleInboundEmail(email, env );
}

}

This is an example of a XY Problem, a point of view you've already heard. Relying on unstructured text in the email to update the quote is a fragile solution. If you insist on using email, give them a button or a link to approve and include a form in the email with values they can change. This can be done with VF email template (example along these lines)
